# A small confusion in network flows (conservation constraints).

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

I'm reading the *Handbook of Graph Theory*.

> [image]
>   [image]

I guess It says that the sum of the flows *going* is equal do the sum of flows *going back*, I'm confused about what is the value of the flow going back, let's take a silly example:

$$\displaystyle \begin{matrix}
{}&{}&{\tiny 10}&{}&{}\\ 
{}&{v}&{\rightarrow}&{w}&{}\\ 
{\tiny 10}&{\uparrow}&{}&{\downarrow}&{\tiny 10}\\ 
{}&{s}&{}&{t}&{}
\end{matrix}$$

Then taking the only possible edge, I have $10$ going. But I have $0$ going back, isn't? Then it doesn't make sense to use **D2** ans say that $10=0$. I am confused here.

Comment: The conservation of flow is required for all vertices *except* $s$ and $t$, i.e., "for each vertex $v\in V-\{s,t\}$"

Comment: @Casteels Yes. But I'm only applying it to $v,w$.

Comment: Ok the way you described your example is confusing, since you say "taking the only possible vertex". Anyways, both $v$ and $w$ satisfy the conservation constraints. Look at all the arrows around one of them, say $v$. Some of the arrows point to $v$, and some point away from $v$. The conservation constraints say that the total flow on the arrows pointing to $v$ must equal the total flow on the arrows pointing away from $v$. For both $v$ and $w$, this says $10=10$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I usually confuse edge with vertex.

Comment: @Casteels Got it. But is it possible to understand it from $\sum_{(w,v)\in E} f(w,v)=\sum_{(v,w)\in E}f(v,w)$? I was trying to understand it from the formula and failed. From this, I understand that the sum of the values going are the same of the sum of the values coming back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they write "$(x,y)\in E$" you should visualize this as an arrow starting at $x$ and pointing to $y$. Something like "$x\to y$". Notice that the order that $x$ and $y$ appear in the notation $(x,y)\in E$ is meaningful, unlike in undirected graphs.

Now the conservation constraints are written here $$\sum_{(w,v)\in E} f(w,v)=\sum_{(v,w)\in E} f(v,w) \text{ for each } v\in V-\{s,t\}.$$

This actually means that you have $|V|-2$ different constraints, one for each vertex $v\in V-\{s,t\}$. Each constraint means the following.

Take any vertex $v\in V$ except $s$ and $t$. First, add up the flow values over *all* edges in $E$ that are pointing *to* $v$. Call this sum $F_\text{in}(v)$. (This is the left side of the equation in the constraint, i.e., $F_\text{in}(v)=\sum_{(w,v)\in E} f(w,v)$).

Now add up the flow values over all edges in $E$ pointing *out* of $v$. Call this sum $F_\text{out}(v)$. (This is the ride side of the equation in the constraint).

Then the conservation constraint for $v$ is satisfied if and only if $F_\text{in}(v)=F_\text{out}(v)$.

In your example if you take $v$, there is only one edge pointing into $v$, giving $F_\text{in}(v)=10$ and one edge pointing out of $v$, giving $F_\text{out}(v)=10$. Since $10=10$, the conservation constraint is satisfied for $v$. Next, you have to check that the conservation constraint is satisfied for $w$. Again we have $F_\text{in}(w)=10=F_\text{out}(w)$, and so the conservation constraint is satisfied for $w$. Thus all the conservation constraints are satisfied for your example.

Comment: Got it, but then it should be something like: $\sum_{(v,w)\in E} f(v,w)=\sum_{(w,t)\in E} f(w,t)$, no? I guess this transmits better the idea of the incoming vertex and the outgoing vertex. It would be easier to see that $v\rightarrow w \rightarrow t$.

Comment: Yeah that would work too. It's an aesthetic choice i guess.